# How to create a togglebutton that only appears after data has downloaded?

Tags: java, android, json, class

I am new to android programming.

I have built myself some code, what I am trying to do is:

1. When MainActivity is loaded, don't show a button.
2. When JSON has successfully loaded, show a toggleButton
3. Based on the JSON data, the toggleButton is loaded as ON or OFF

I don't know how to do this so I employed the following strategy.
In MainActivity.onCreate, I declared toggleButton *toggleSugar*.

When JSON is downloaded, I update *toggleSugar* to VISIBLE or INVISIBLE.

But *toggleSugar* is in method onCreate, whereas JSON activity is in method doInBackground in subclass GetButtonState extends ASyncClass()

So when I try to update *toggleSugar* from JSON success code block, it can't access *toggleSugar* object.

Second strategy was to declare *toggleSugar* under MainActivity root, before onCreate. This makes the app crash.

My code is as follows:

```
package com.cyberialearning.aswitch;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       ToggleButton toggleSugar = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toggleSugar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        new GetButtonState().execute();

        final TextView statusmsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        boolean dataReceived=true;

        if (dataReceived==false) {
            toggleSugar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        toggleSugar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    statusmsg.setText("ButtonisOn");
                } else {
                    statusmsg.setText("ButtonisOff");
                    ;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    void testfunction() {
        Log.e(TAG, "testfunction");
        toggleSugar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    private class GetButtonState extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        final TextView statusmsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        boolean dataReceived=true;          
        ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);   
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            statusmsg.setText("Please wait. Connecting ...");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Trying to get JSON data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            String url = "http://www.nusantara.com.my/testjson.html";
            String jsonStr=null;
            try {
                jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
                jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("callBackFunction(", "");
            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("Cannot Communicate With "+url);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {
                    AlertDialog aDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setMessage("It is possible that the server is down temporarily.\n\nDoes this device have internet access?").setTitle("Cannot communicate with server.")
                            .setNeutralButton("Shutdown App", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) { finish(); } }).create();
                    //disable the back button
                    aDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() { @Override public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { return true; } });                        
                    dataReceived=false;    

                } });
                return null;
            }
            jsonStr = jsonStr.replace (");","");
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    String currentStatus = jsonObj.getString("status");
                    Log.e(TAG, "received JSON status: " + currentStatus);                                            
                    testfunction();
                } catch (final JSONException e) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "Invalid JSON format (test with curiousconcepts) : " + e.getMessage()); runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }});
                    }
            } else {
             MESSAGE IS NULL : POSSIBLE SERVER PROBLEM - hosting
                Log.e(TAG, "JSON is null.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dataReceived=false;
                        statusmsg.setText("Please wait. Connecting ...");


                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.e(TAG,"in onPostExecute function.");

        }

    }
}
```

I have also tried to do :

```
toggleSugar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

when the JSON has successfully downloaded, but it doesn't work.

I've also tried to call a function that is outside the subclass *testFunction()* to refer to *toggleSugar* which is outside the subclass, but this also doesn't work.

Please help.

Comment: `toggleSugar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` add this in postExecute of asynctask.

Comment: the reply by Mohammed Fathi below is similar to your comment, I have accepted this as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first , you need to move the declaration of the ToggleButton from the onCreate method  and declare it at the beginning of the class like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ToggleButton  toggleSugar ;

//......

}
```

then get the refrence to the toggle button inside the onCreate method :

```
toggleSugar = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
```

after that you can access it from your onPostExcute method as follows :

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            toggleSugar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, however, the app keeps crashing. I get FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Comment: Hello. The app crashes because of a toggleSugar.setVisibility code in void testfunction() in the middle. After removing that, it runs without crash. I don't know for sure if it works because it is instant. Is there a way to set a delay for 2-3 seconds before it calls for the JSON data in the server just to test? I have accepted your reply as answer.